# Django: How to return a user to correct pagination page after editing or updating?

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-pagination

I am editing a content from table which has pagination in it. If i update a user which is at the page no 9 and save that user, it will return me to page no 1.

I want it to return to a same page where user was previously there that is at page no 9.

Any help regarding the same would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass to the editing page the page number you were on, in a query parameter. And keep track of it and when editing/updating is successful you redirect back to that page number.

In your form include a next field. Where to redirect in case of success.

Comment: Bogdan the problem is I have 2 functions one for listing and other for updating so.How can I pass page value from one function to the other functions. I mean to say that page value is available in listing function so how can I use that value in updating function.